# How to pass a custom redis url to Rack::Session::Redis?

Tags: ruby, session, redis, rack

I want to set encrypted session cookies with the data being stored in Redis.

I've included the gem, bundled it, and here's my `config.ru`

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/session/redis'
use Rack::Session::Redis

require './config/application'
run MyApp::Application.new
```

Looks like I can pass a `:redis_server` [in there somehow](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/redis.rb#L11), but how do I do it? I'd expect something like use `Rack::Session::Redis.new(:redis_server => 'redis://wherever')`, though that's obviously not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the options as an arg to `use`:

```
use Rack::Session::Redis, :redis_server => 'redis://wherever'
```

Rack [converts this to `Rack::Session::Redis.new(the_app, :redis_server => 'redis://wherever')`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb#L86) when constructing the app.